# drawimage multiple times on canvas

Tags: javascript

How would I go about spawning in enemies once the current enemies hit an x location of 900?

it would have to be like

```
if(enemy.x<=900){    
    //spawn enemies
}
```

here is a jsfiddle to show you what I mean, the blocks moving left i want to have multiples of them
http://jsfiddle.net/h8u1n3fj/
I need the current enemies to stay on the board while these are spawned as well, and just have it so that there are multiple groups of enemies that stay on the board after each time a person hits 900.

```
var requestAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||   window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimFrame
var place = [74,111,148,185,222,259,296,333,370];
var rand = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var rand2 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var rand3 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var rand4 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var rand5 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var rand6 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var rand7 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var rand8 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var rand9 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];

console.log(rand);

var move = setInterval(function () {
    enemy.x -= 45;
}, 500);
//drawing the character

function drawChar(x,y){
    enemy.y = rand;
    enemy.y2 = rand2;
    enemy.y3 = rand3;
    enemy.y4 = rand4;
    enemy.y5 = rand5;
    enemy.y6 = rand6;
    enemy.y7 = rand7;
    enemy.y8 = rand8;
    enemy.y9 = rand9;

    context.drawImage(tile3,enemy.x,enemy.y,tileWidth,tileHeight);
    context.drawImage(tile3,enemy.x,enemy.y2,tileWidth,tileHeight);
    context.drawImage(tile3,enemy.x,enemy.y3,tileWidth,tileHeight);
    context.drawImage(tile3,enemy.x,enemy.y4,tileWidth,tileHeight);
    context.drawImage(tile3,enemy.x,enemy.y5,tileWidth,tileHeight);
    context.drawImage(tile3,enemy.x,enemy.y6,tileWidth,tileHeight);
    context.drawImage(tile3,enemy.x,enemy.y7,tileWidth,tileHeight);
    context.drawImage(tile3,enemy.x,enemy.y8,tileWidth,tileHeight);
    context.drawImage(tile3,enemy.x,enemy.y9,tileWidth,tileHeight);

    requestAnimFrame(drawChar);
    if(enemy.x<=0){
        enemy.x=990;
        rand = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
    }

    else {

        return true;
    }

}
```

Also, if you have any suggestions on how to make the code cleaner, feel free to, but I mainly want to be able to spawn these enemies each time x equals 900 and keep the current enemies on the board.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your list of enemies (rand to rand9), is being used until it gets to where enemy.x equals zero. Now, rather than using one list of enemies, wouldn't it be nice if we could just spawn enemy lists, one after the other, without overwriting variables, and then discard enemy lists once they reach zero? **You need to use object-programming in order to solve your problem.** A well documented tutorial can be found here: http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter8.html. After learning a little object-oriented programming (OOP), you will be able to make a "blueprint" for your enemy lists, allowing you to create them and position them, while keeping them independent of one another.

Comment: can you or someone elaborate on how I would turn        context.drawImage(tile3,enemy.x,enemy.y2,tileWidth,tileHeight);
 to an image? I know about object-oriented programming, but I don't know how to stick an image into an object